# How can I fix error with CLR winforms app on VS C++?

Tags: c++, clr

I have tried to make winforms on VS and C++. Used for this CLR empty project(.NET Framework). Added UI winforms and can't compile simple code in a MyForm.cpp:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace WizzFactory_app_winforms;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1);
    return 0;
}
```

I gon an error: name must be a namespace name
on the string

```
using namespace WizzFactory_app_winforms;
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

namespace should write without _. Just Project1. And it will works.

Comment: The underscores are fine, but the `using namespace` has to match the namespace name actually used in `MyForm.h`